# Apple - UISearchBar issue with UINavigationConroller

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar

Using storyboard I have created one `UINavigationController` and two `UITableViewContorllers`:

[image: MasterViewContoller] (`MasterViewContoller`)

and

[image: Level2Contoller] (`Level2Contoller`).

Both `UITableViewControllers` have `UISearchBar` at top. `MasterViewContoller` is set as root of `UINavigationConroller`.

Now the problem is that when I use below code to go to level2, I am not getting a seach bar on `Level2Contoller`.

```
level2Contoller *l2 = [[level2Contoller alloc]init];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController :l2 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I used this:

```
level2Contoller * level2Contoller = [self.storyboard   instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"id1"];
```

instead of:

```
level2Contoller *l2 = [[level2Contoller alloc]init];
```